# Wordpress plugins are storing transients on database

Tags: wordpress, memcached

I thought that transient data should be stored on memcached instead of database. The following is phpinfo inside wordpress (phpinfo plugin), and it shows it is

```
Active persistent connections 0 
Version 2.2.7
Revision$Revision: 327750$
memcache.allow_failover 1
memcache.chunk_size 8192
memcache.default_port 11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms 1000 
memcache.hash_function crc32
memcache.hash_strategy standard 
memcache.max_failover_attempts 20
```

My wp options table has almost a million rows as all transient data is being stored in DB, I use a few plugins on woocommercer that store quite a bit of data, such as the History plugin and the Cart plugin.

Is there something else that I need to do for transient data to be stored in memcached?

thanks for the help